# Is the (inverse) image of an ideal also an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

How would you go about proving(or disproving) these two statements.  I feel like they are both true but am struggling with the proof technique/strategy of showing these statements.

If $ϕ: R → S$ is a ring homomorphism and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $ϕ(I)$ is an ideal of $S$.

If $ϕ: R → S$ is a ring homomorphism and $I$ is an ideal of $S$, then $ϕ^{−1}(I)$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: I won't tell you that they are both true, but maybe starting to try to prove each will tell you something. For the first, you probably remember from group theory that the image of a subgroup under a group homomorphism is a subgroup, so $\phi(I)$ is at least a subgroup of the additive group of $S$. Now you need to check whether for each $s \in S$ and $r \in I$ one has $s\phi(r) = \phi(r')$ for some $r' \in I$. Is this always achievable? If you can't show this quickly, it probably isn't true -- try playing around with some examples.

Answer (score 3):

If $\Phi$ isn't surjective then the first statement is false; nonetheless $\Phi(I)$ is an ideal of $\Phi(R)$.

The second statement is true, $\Phi^{-1}(I)$ is a subgroup of $R$, now show that : $$\forall (r,x)\in R\times\Phi^{-1}(I),r\cdot x\in\Phi^{-1}(I).$$